# How to fix ansible problems at fact gathering time?

Tags: ansible, devops

When gathering facts, provisioning fails for the first host with the error you see below.

```
PLAY [surveylab] ************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************
failed: [192.168.56.101] => {"cmd": "/usr/bin/facter --puppet --json", "failed": true, "rc": 2}
msg: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
ok: [192.168.56.102]
```

This problem can be fixed by doing:

```
ln -sf /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 /usr/bin/ruby
```

Which I want to do as a pre_task in my playbook like this:

```
pre_tasks:
- name: symlink expected ruby bin from versioned bin
  command: ln -sf /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 /usr/bin/ruby
```

It doesn't work, the error still shows. The obvious explanation is that when the facts are gathered, the problem still exists... but how are such things done?

Comment: hiro already provided a technical solution, let me add the philosophical jargon: *IMHO* if your `facter` is broken (say due to broken `ruby`) then you should be fixing your 'base image' instead-of / in-addition-to adding the fix to your playbook. If you are forced to work around such issues, then it kinda goes against the whole purpose of using ansible (or any CM automation).

Comment: Yeah, it's becoming more clear that you're right.

Comment: indeed - it would be much cleaner to fix this broken `ruby` install before automating anything.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to write a separate playbook that just sets the link - there you would have to disable the gathering of the facts:

```
- name: 'some playbook'
  gather_facts: no
```

might work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the facter package is installed on the target machine(s). For example, on RHEL/CentOS:

```
sudo yum install facter
```